# How to make multiple formula lines work in org-mode tables

Tags: emacs, formula, org-mode

I have an org-mode document with a table and several formulas. For better readability I'd like to have one line per formula. According to org-mode documentation this should be possible. However, the example "using multiple #+TBLFM" lines from this site 
http://orgmode.org/manual/Editing-and-debugging-formulas.html
doesn't work for me. When I C-c C-c on the second formula line of the example table (see below) nothing happens.

```
| x | y |
|---+---|
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
#+TBLFM: $2=$1*1
#+TBLFM: $2=$1*2
```

Can anybody point me to a solution (other than having the formulas in one line separated by double colons)? I'm using Emacs 24.3.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: What does `M-x org-version` show?

Comment: Org-mode version 7.9.3f (release_7.9.3f-17-g7524ef @ /usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation that you linked to is for the latest release of `org-mode`, which is currently version 8.2.5.

Documentation for table formulas in version 7.9.3f, which is shipped with Emacs, [does not mention support for multiple `#+TBLFM` lines](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Editing-and-debugging-formulas.html#Editing-and-debugging-formulas).

It is possible to [upgrade `org-mode`](http://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html) to a version that supports multiple `#+TBLFM` lines. I recommend using the [official `org-mode` ELPA repository](http://orgmode.org/elpa.html), which you'll have to add to your `package-archives` list (see the link for details).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Chris! I tried to install a newer version of org-mode via M-x package-install RET org. This, however, installed the exact same version again. As I prefer to use the Emacs packaging system instead of pushing files around myself I thus didn't upgrade. I nevertheless think it's highly likely your answer is correct. Thus - thanks again!

Comment: @user3292479, I have clarified my answer. `org-mode` has its own ELPA repository. If you add that to your `package-archives` as outlined in the linked page, you should be able to get the latest Org via `package-install`.

Comment: Thanks again for your advice, Chris. Following the procedure mentioned on the page, however, resulted in re-installing exactly the same version (7.9.3f) again. It is also noted on this page that this repository "contains the same set of files that are included in GNU Emacs". Therefore probably I'll have to wait until the newer version of org-mode is officially packaged for Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following in my init file to install the latest `org-mode`. I keep it earlier in my init file so that it is executed before the org-mode shipped with emacs is loaded

```
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
(unless (package-installed-p 'org-plus-contrib)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'org-plus-contrib))
```

The package `org-plus-contrib` installs the latest `org-mode` plus some additional addons for `org-mode`. I guess the statement

> contains the same set of files that are included in GNU Emacs

Refers to the fact that `org` package does not include the `contrib` packages.